# counts' division doesn't work in full code

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, count

I do have a problem with a task because my division value is different when I use it alone and when I use it in full code. Let's say I do this code:

```
SELECT (count(paimta))::numeric / count(distinct paimta) as average
FROM Stud.Egzempliorius;
```

and finally a number I get is 2.(6)7, but when I use it in full code which is:

```
SELECT Stud.Egzempliorius.Paimta, COUNT(PAIMTA) as PaimtaKnyga

FROM Stud.Skaitytojas, Stud.Egzempliorius

WHERE Stud.Skaitytojas.Nr=Stud.Egzempliorius.Skaitytojas

GROUP BY Stud.Egzempliorius.Paimta

HAVING count(paimta) > (count(paimta))::numeric / count(distinct paimta);
```

it's value changes because division is not working anymore and let's say instead of having

```
    HAVING count(paimta) > (count(paimta))::numeric / count(distinct paimta);
```

my codes turns into

```
    HAVING count(paimta) > (count(paimta))::numeric;
```

and these values are equal, so I can't get final answer. That's database I use https://klevas.mif.vu.lt/~baronas/dbvs/biblio/show-table.php?table=Stud.Egzempliorius

I was struggling for 10 hours now and finally I've lost my patience... So, my question is what I have to do that this code:

```
SELECT (count(paimta))::numeric / count(distinct paimta) as average
FROM Stud.Egzempliorius;
```

value doesn't change in full code?

Picture how it changes [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klVOr.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution fails because the two queries operate on a different groups of rows. The first query does a computation over the whole dataset, while the second one groups by `paimta`.

One option would have been to use window functions, but as far as concerns Postgres does not support `count(distinct)` as a window function.

I think that the simplest approach is to use a subquery :

```
select e.paimta, count(paimta) as paimtaknyga
from stud.skaitytojas s
inner join stud.egzempliorius e on s.nr = e.skaitytojas
group by e.paimta
having count(paimta) > (
    select (count(paimta))::numeric / count(distinct paimta) from stud.egzempliorius
)
```

Comment: It finally works, just needed to change "where" with word "on". Thank you very much, I appreciate your time!